# Some code help needed with html5 audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio

What is happening is it repeats some 1 over and over

Globals:

```
var song1 = new Audio("songs/loop1.mp3");
var song2 = new Audio("songs/loop2.mp3");
var song3 = new Audio("songs/loop3.mp3");
var song4 = new Audio("songs/loop4.mp3");
var song5 = new Audio("songs/loop5.mp3");
var song6 = new Audio("songs/loop6.mp3");
var song7 = new Audio("songs/loop7.mp3");
var song8 = new Audio("songs/loop8.mp3");
var song9 = new Audio("songs/loop9.mp3");
var song10 = new Audio("songs/loop10.mp3");
var song11 = new Audio("songs/loop11.mp3");
var songList = [];
var currentSong = 1;

songList.push(song1,song2,song3,song4,song5,song6,song7,song8,song9,song10,song11);

var song = songList[0];
```

Before game loop I call:

```
song.play();
```

Listener: (I have feeling this stays with same var and does not move up as song points at new var in array?)

```
song.addEventListener('ended', NextSong);
```

it calls:

```
function NextSong()
 {

currentSong++;

if(currentSong > songList.lenght);
{
currentSong = 1;
}

song.play();

}
```

Comment: Is it as simple as an incorrect spelling of the word "length" in the conditional?

Comment: When are you changing `song`?  You probably need a line like `song = songList[currentSong]` somewhere

Comment: There's a typo in your function as DrC pointed out. It should be `if(currentSong > songList.length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `song.play()` in your `NextSong` function to `songList[currentsong].play()`

also change `lenght` to `length`

and you can make your function's code prettier

```
function nextSong{
    currentSong = (++currentSong)%songList.length;
    songList[currentsong].play();
}
```

**EDIT**

if you need to start loop all your songs. In your code it seams that first one is called once and only others are in loop (0, 1, 2, ..., 10, 1, 2, 3...)